# Cannot get list object from Swagger

Tags: c#, list, swagger

I have created a swagger to study and I have a problem.

My input in swagger page:

```
{
  "content": "string",
  "productId": 0,
  "postId": 0,
  "statusIdDetail": 0
}
```

and my object is:

```
public List<PostDetailVm> DetailPost { get; set; }

public class PostDetailVm
    {
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public int StatusIdDetail { get; set; }

    }
```

My API:

```
[HttpPost("CreatePost")]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePost([FromForm] PostCreateViewModel objEmp)
```

When I executed, the DetailPost is count = 0, can anyone help this situation?

Comment: How does PostCreateViewModel fit with PostDetailVm and DetailPost?

Comment: Why is the input a JSON object if the endpoint is expecting `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: @Ralf Sorry I'm so busy yesterday, DetailPost is a list PostDetailVm in model PostCreateViewModel, model has many other property so I forget to mention here, just only DetailPost get count = 0 when I CreatePost, others work normal.

Comment: @Helen thank for your assist, I'll research more about the  multipart/form-data.